# where is android keyboard app located?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, keyboard, aosp

I uninstalled the stock AOSP keyboard from my android cyanogenmod 11 I have the ROM zip file so I'm fetching the keyboard to put it back but I don't know where it is, it's neither under /system/app nor under /system/priv-app

```
rahman@SISYPHUS:~/Downloads/lineage> ls -l system/app/
total 104076
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  1686064 Feb 29  2008 Apollo.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    33302 Feb 29  2008 BasicDreams.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2003305 Feb 29  2008 Bluetooth.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   295592 Feb 29  2008 BluetoothExt.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  3229555 Feb 29  2008 Browser.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   980865 Feb 29  2008 Calculator.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2039531 Feb 29  2008 Calendar.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  4186076 Feb 29  2008 Camera2.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   455626 Feb 29  2008 CellBroadcastReceiver.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   164413 Feb 29  2008 CertInstaller.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2433831 Feb 29  2008 CMFileManager.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   311660 Feb 29  2008 CMHome.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  7898628 Feb 29  2008 CMWallpapers.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2963113 Feb 29  2008 DeskClock.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   111050 Feb 29  2008 Development.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   427255 Feb 29  2008 DocumentsUI.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   238325 Feb 29  2008 DownloadProviderUi.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   733567 Feb 29  2008 DSPManager.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  5194472 Feb 29  2008 Email.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  1174970 Feb 29  2008 Exchange2.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   279206 Feb 29  2008 Galaxy4.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  6223567 Feb 29  2008 Gallery2.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users   206402 Feb 29  2008 GoogleContactsSyncAdapter.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    61557 Feb 29  2008 HoloSpiralWallpaper.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    12165 Feb 29  2008 HTMLViewer.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    10448 Feb 29  2008 InCallUI.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    74638 Feb 29  2008 KeyChain.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users 42780317 Feb 29  2008 LatinIME.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  1765803 Feb 29  2008 LiveWallpapers.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   180192 Feb 29  2008 LiveWallpapersPicker.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  8629786 Feb 29  2008 LockClock.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   239931 Feb 29  2008 MagicSmokeWallpapers.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    90493 Feb 29  2008 NoiseField.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   391583 Feb 29  2008 PackageInstaller.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     5634 Feb 29  2008 PacProcessor.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   105916 Feb 29  2008 PhaseBeam.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   803882 Feb 29  2008 PhotoPhase.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   478492 Feb 29  2008 PhotoTable.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    18151 Feb 29  2008 PicoTts.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   241796 Feb 29  2008 PrintSpooler.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     3691 Feb 29  2008 Provision.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   170124 Feb 29  2008 SoundRecorder.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   112484 Feb 29  2008 Stk.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   100002 Feb 29  2008 TelephonyProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   564672 Feb 29  2008 Term.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   189585 Feb 29  2008 Torch.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    15787 Feb 29  2008 UserDictionaryProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  5704511 Feb 29  2008 VideoEditor.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   207362 Feb 29  2008 VisualizationWallpapers.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   224525 Feb 29  2008 VoicePlus.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     7116 Feb 29  2008 WAPPushManager.apk
rahman@SISYPHUS:~/Downloads/lineage> ls -l system/priv-app/
total 71160
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   141551 Feb 29  2008 BackupRestoreConfirmation.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users   233655 Feb 29  2008 CalendarProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  1490703 Feb 29  2008 CMAccount.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   299723 Feb 29  2008 CMUpdater.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  3178247 Feb 29  2008 Contacts.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   429926 Feb 29  2008 ContactsProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    20378 Feb 29  2008 DefaultContainerService.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  4276606 Feb 29  2008 Dialer.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   504601 Feb 29  2008 DownloadProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    26999 Feb 29  2008 ExternalStorageProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    14793 Feb 29  2008 FusedLocation.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users   127421 Feb 29  2008 GoogleBackupTransport.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users   303583 Feb 29  2008 GoogleFeedback.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users  5714918 Feb 29  2008 GoogleLoginService.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users   129466 Feb 29  2008 GooglePartnerSetup.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users  2358561 Feb 29  2008 GoogleServicesFramework.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   163176 Feb 29  2008 InputDevices.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2306822 Feb 29  2008 Keyguard.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   131631 Feb 29  2008 MediaProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  3065387 Feb 29  2008 Mms.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     5691 Feb 29  2008 OneTimeInitializer.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users  6126834 Feb 29  2008 Phonesky.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users  8536422 Feb 29  2008 PrebuiltGmsCore.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     8179 Feb 29  2008 ProxyHandler.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users 19786541 Feb 29  2008 Settings.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   138839 Feb 29  2008 SettingsProvider.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rahman users  1533478 Feb 29  2008 SetupWizard.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users     6889 Feb 29  2008 SharedStorageBackup.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    56582 Feb 29  2008 Shell.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2425108 Feb 29  2008 SystemUI.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  4068193 Feb 29  2008 TeleService.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2560728 Feb 29  2008 ThemeChooser.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    27912 Feb 29  2008 ThemesProvider.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users  2223276 Feb 29  2008 Trebuchet.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   129746 Feb 29  2008 VoiceDialer.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users    63231 Feb 29  2008 VpnDialogs.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 rahman users   176798 Feb 29  2008 WallpaperCropper.apk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default AOSP keyboard is `/system/app/LatinIME.apk`. IME is an acronym for [Input Method Editor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method).